# Partial Variable length string removal in Python

Tags: python, string

I'm unfamiliar with Python, I've been trying to teach myself to help automate my work.

Right now my job is to remove the front portion of any address string that begins with "Suite XYZ".  Sometimes it's just "suite A" sometimes it's "Suite 12A". I want to remove those, but avoid removing too much from the front of the string, where the rest of the address is, so I can't just clip a set amount off every time a string starts with "suite". I was thinking of just looking for "suite *_*_" and if the 2nd or 3rd characters were a space, removing only "suite _*" or "suite _*" respectively and returning the string.

Would it be better to just count the spaces and cut at the 2nd space? So "Suite AAA (Rest Of Address)" would get cut between AAA and the rest of the string?

While looking for help on this, I kept seeing something about regular expressions. Is that worth looking into?

Comment: Actually, it depends on the data as well. Do you have multiple lines, one address per line, some of which begin with "Suite XX" that need to be trimmed? If so, regular expressions will help like Luke suggested below.

Comment: I have several lines. The file has a row for column names and then hundreds of lines with information in a CSV spreadsheet. I'm tinkering around with the csv module and have managed to be able to locate the address column for each row, so I believe I'm working with an iterable string object?? Some lines begin with Suite, others are already clean. I might have to look into Reg Expressions if I can't get 2rs2ts' space-based solution to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely look into regular expressions. For this type of problem, they can't be beat:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('(s|S)uite\s+\w+\s*', '', 'Suite 134A xxx')
'xxx'
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are great, but you have well-defined requirements on your strings. According to your question, they always take the following form: `"Suite AAA (Rest of address)"`. As long as the string always starts with `"Suite"`, followed by a space, followed by 1 to 3 characters, followed by another space, and then followed by anything, you can just use splitting and slicing.

```
>>> suite = "Suite 12A Honeymoon Suite"
>>> suffix = " ".join(suite.split()[2:])
>>> print suffix
'Honeymoon Suit'
```

What this does is split the string into substrings delineated by each space (`["Suite", "12A", "Honeymoon", "Suite"]`), then it joins each disjoint substring from index 2 (the third one) on, connecting them with spaces.

Comment: I like this a lot, if it would work! It doesn't seem to spit out a Suite-less address :( Does my using Python 2.7.5 affect this or...?

Comment: @user2533406 Based on what you said in another comment, it looks like you're using a CSV spreadsheet; I've never used CSV, but I think you're not dealing with strings such as `"Suite AAA (Rest of address)"`. What *do* you get when you use my solution?

Comment: It spits the exact same string out. I even tried it with a string I wrote in another script. Copying your solution out yielded the same result :(

And I am dealing with strings in this format, at least I believe I am. 

        'for row in reader:

            addr=row[25]

            
            print addr'


Addr prints out an address in the format I've specified. EDIT: I am bad at formatting too, apparently :(

Comment: So if I do the split, assign that to the suite object, then do a join on that object, it removes the Suite and Number, but the output is this: ['Honeymoon', 'Suite']

Comment: @user2533406 You probably forgot to assign the result of the `join` to something.

Comment: That I did! Sorry, I wasn't entirely familiar with the ins and outs of joins and splits, I'm learning as I go, but this is a huge help! Thank you :)

Comment: @user2533406 Not a problem. Go ahead and accept either my answer or Luke's, whichever solved your problem :)